# Is $\int_a^a f(x) dx$ always zero?

Tags: integration

Is the result:

$$\int_a^a f(x) \,\text{d}x = 0$$

always zero?

This seems obvious at first, but what if $f(x)$ diverges at $x=a$?

[For example, Wolfram Alpha tells me](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%5B1%2Fx%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C0%7D%5D&x=0&y=0)

$$\int_0^0 \frac{1}{x}\,\text{d}x = 0\qquad (1)$$

[But:](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%5B1%2Fx%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000001%7D%5D&x=0&y=0)
$$\int_0^{1\times10^{-40}}\frac{1}{x}\,\text{d}x = \infty\qquad (2)$$

As far as I can tell, this happens no matter how small I set the upper limit of integration.

Is $(1)$ correct? Why is it true, even if both $f$ and it's antiderivative diverge at the point?

If it's not true in general, what conditions must $f(x)$ satisfy?

**Edit**

I do not believe my question is a true duplicate of the other. While the question about integrating on a point is shared, my question is more general, since that one concentrates on s specific (complicated) integral. I ask what is needed for general $f(x)$.  If you are the answers to that question, neither is generalizable to other integrands.

Comment: I suggest that you ask the main question as: What conditions should $f(x)$ satisfy in order to have $\int_a^a f(x) dx = 0$.

Comment: What if you had a function that was defined only on $x = a$ and no where else? What if it is not only defined on $x = a$, but it is infinite at that point? http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221a/delta.pdf

Comment: The usual definition for Lebesgue integration, which is a wider class of integration than Riemann Integration is that $0\cdot\infty=0$. So (1) and (2) are correct.

Comment: Good question. Briefly, the Riemann integral make sense only when the function $f$ is bounded over the domain of integration. So, I don't think (1) makes sense as a Riemann integral. As a generalized integral, you cannot approach (1) by integrals like (2), since (2) is itself an improper integral. The problem really is the lower limit of integration: the function $1/x$ is not defined at zero.  However, in measure theory, $\int_a^a f d\mu=0$ is always correct.

Comment: @JoeAaron: Techincally, you still have to define $f(x)=1/x$ to be $\textit something$ at $x=0$ for $\int_a^a f d\mu=0$ to make sense.

Comment: @Chilango: ok, got it, although here there is no problem in defining $f=\infty$ at zero.

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant: the Dirac delta is not really a function on the measure space, rather a distribution. No matter what ever physicists claim ;)

Comment: @JoeAaron: Yes you can but you do have to say it I guess however silly it seems,

Comment: @BolzWeir Took your advice thanks.   I think I like some of the anwers I've gotten, but I will let the question sit for a bit before accepting anything.  If anyone could give a quick introduction to what Lesbesgue measures or Lesbesgue integration is that would be awesome

Comment: possible duplicate of [$\mathcal{I}=\int\limits_0^0 \{x\}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\,\mathrm dx=0\textrm{ or undefined ?}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311840/mathcali-int-limits-00-x-lfloor-x-rfloor-mathrm-dx-0-textrm-or-u)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $M$ be a subset of $\mathbb R$ such that $M$ has Lebesgue measure $0$.
Let $f$ be a function on $M$ such that $f(x) = \infty$ for all $x\in M$.
I claim $\int_M f(x) dx = 0$.
The proof is as follows.

For an integer $n\ge 1$, let $f_n$ be a constant $n$ function on $M$.
Then $f_1\le f_2\le \cdots$ and $\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$ for all $x\in M$.
By Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem, $\int_M f(x) dx = \text{lim}_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_M f_n(x) dx$. The right-hand side of the equation is obviously $0$.

Comment: I like this answer.  Will accept if can add some more details about what a Lesbesgue measure and the corresponding theorem are. Nevertheless +1

Answer (score 0):

The example $f(x) = 1/x$ is not (Lebesgue) integrable on $(0, a)$ for any $a>0$, so $a\mapsto\int_0^a f(x) \mathrm d x$ need not to be continuous at $a=0$.

However, if $f$ is integrable, then $a\mapsto\int_0^a f(x) \mathrm d x$ is continuous in $a$ and 
$$ \lim_{a\to 0} \int_0^a f(x) \mathrm d x = \int_0^0 f(x) \mathrm d x = 0.$$